# Middleman installed but binary cannot be found

Tags: ruby, rbenv, middleman

I just installed Middleman on my Mac (OS 10.8.2) but am unable to generate a new project. I have Xcode installed. Can anyone tell me what I might have done wrong?

```
$ middleman init moi
-bash: middleman: command not found
```

```
$ gem list
middleman (3.0.12)
middleman-core (3.0.12)
middleman-more (3.0.12)
middleman-sprockets (3.0.9)
```

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

I'm using rbenv. This is my path:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/shims:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/me/downloads/mongodb/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: What’s your `$PATH`? Are you using rbenv or RVM?

Comment: I'm using rbenv. Updated OP with my path. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Have you run `rbenv rehash`? This is usually necessary after just installing a gem so rbenv can generate the needed shims.

Comment: That was the problem.

Comment: Added as an answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you’ve just installed a new gem in a Ruby installation managed by rbenv, you should run

```
rbenv rehash
```

after installing. This generates the shims for the newly-installed gem that will allow you to run it. You can read more in [rbenv’s readme](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#rbenv-rehash).